# how to build a scene with imported fbx objects

Tags: python, scripting, import, .fbx

In the following two lines of code:

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx( filepath = "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/plants_from_internet/Plant_one/Plant_Model/Plant_FBX.fbx" )
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(location=(2,0,0))
```

the first imports a scene, the second "imports" a mesh to a specific location.  What I want to do is import the scene as an object (can that even be done?) and place it in my scene at locations and orientations of my choosing, with python.  The benefit of of working with the fbx (or equivalent files) is that they can be files produced by others that come with texturing, etc.  From my research so far, I'm afraid that the solution to this is not simple.

Comment: After the import (well for most cases) The newly imported objects have context (`context.selected_objects`).  Can move all, parent to empty move empty or add to a collection and add instance of to scene.

Comment: @batFINGER thanks for the tip!  will check it out!